# How does Fl4k's "All My BFFs" skill work?

Tags: borderlands-3

Fl4k has an ability "All My BFFs" (in the Jabber tree) whose effect (when maxed out) reads:

> Allies share 50% of Fl4k's Health Regeneration.

Who counts as "allies"? Just other players and their pets, or NPCs too?

What does "share" mean here? Do I gain less health when joined by an ally than I would when playing solo? Does my ally gain less health when we are joined by a third ally than they would if it were just the two of us?

Do allies need to be near me to receive the bonus?

Does this apply to all passive health regeneration I get (such as, perhaps, a shield that grants regen), or just to skills that grant health regeneration?

Comment: I can't confirm this statistically but from my understanding/experience playing Fl4k with that perk is that my teammates all receive health regeneration bonuses equal to 50% of my total health regen

Comment: @n_plum that pretty much aligns with my experience as well. "allies" seems to be players and pets, and the bonuses they get seem to be _in addition_ to what i normally get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *"All My BFFs"* skill provides a percentage of your total health regeneration to all player characters that you're currently playing with. You still retain all of your health regeneration.

---

I use to main Fl4k for co-op, and this was one of my main must-have skills. I can confirm that this includes all sources of health regeneration across skills and gear. I can also confirm that this does not affect your own health regeneration - it's not split up. You retain 100% of your health regeneration.

We were able to confirm that this did not affect non-player characters; and it did not appear to affect other player characters pets. We did not have many occasions where we could test this out, so I might be off on that one. There also didn't appear to be any proximity-related requirements; my mate could be on the other side of the map, and still benefit from my health regeneration.

As a side note, it is possible to stack the skill up to 100% shared regeneration, using additional skill points from a class mod.